# Fixed time range for a grafana panel

Tags: time, range, prometheus, grafana

I'm using several time series panels on my dashboards, which are showing the values based on the selected time range.

Now, I want to add a gauge panel, which should show the number of payment transactions since midnight (although I know all the problems about server restarts, the feature of the rate function, etc. the gauge panel will an interesting part of my dashboard). So my query has to be independant from the selected time range of the dashboard.

I've found the variables  ${__from} und ${__to} in the Grafana docs, but I'm not sure, how I can use them in a query or how to use them flexibel, e.g. getting the current daten/time as "to" and calculating "from" als midnight value.

Has anybody an idea, if this is generally possible?

Thanks in advance
Matthias

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69646933/11344502) answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.